# How to include Partner Information in CiviReports

Tags: civireport

We have created a new (Pickleball) Tournament Event in Civi with On-Line Registration.  As part of the registration, Partner Information (partner's name) can be entered for Men's Doubles Partner, Women's Doubles Partner and/or Mixed Doubles Partner.  However, this information does not seem to be available on CiviReports for the Event.

How can Partner Information be included in CiviReports for Event Participants such that they can be properly link to their partners.  Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

LA Jones

Comment: It would help us if you included your Civi version and CMS (if applicable).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE.  I'm assuming the partner info field is created as a custom field on Participants? What kind of field is it? (It could be a simple text field or a contact reference field to another contact) You should see those custom fields listed at the bottom of the Columns tab on the 'Event Participants List' or 'Attendee List'.  Expand the custom field group and select the partner field.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much for your reply; these are single line text entry fields.  I was not seeing the Partner Info tab at the bottom of the Participant Column as you show on your picture.  I discovered that these custom fields were set to NOT Searchable; once I reconfigured these needed fields to Searchable, the tab now shows up and the fields are available for selection.  Really appreciate your timely response with helpful information!

Comment: @user13100 can you add that as an Answer